# Entity changes made manually are not being identified by EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm changing an entity by hand and after that I'm trying to verify if there is any entity in my DbContext that matches with my changes. The "answer" I expected was "true", however it's "false".
As my code is very complex and with many rules I've created a simple example to try to explain the problem:

```
var propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"MyProperty1", "My value"},
    {"MyProperty2", 10}
};

var entityId = 13;
var entityType = typeof(MyEntity);

// Applies the changes
this.ApplyChanges(db, entityType, entityId, propertyValues);


// This is "false"
var hasEntityWithValue = db.MyEntity.Any(p => p.Id == entityId && p.MyProperty1 != null);

// The "myEntity" is null
var myEntity = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == entityId && p.MyProperty1 != null);

// Gets the entity only by Id
myEntity = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == entityId);

// And when I compare the "MyProperty1" it's "true". Why?????
hasEntityWithValue = myEntity.MyProperty1 != null;
```

The "**ApplyChanges**" method:

```
private void ApplyChanges(DbContext db, Type entityType, int entityId, 
Dictionary<string, object> propertyValues)
{
    var entity = db.Set(entityType).Find(entityId);
    foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
    {
        var propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(propertyValue.Key);

        // Sets the value
        propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, propertyValue.Value);
    }

    db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
}
```

I believe this is happening because when I query the entities I'm querying them in the database instead of the EntityFramework "cache".

But is there a way to force EntityFramework identify the changes when I query the entities in the DbContext by using the IQueryable extension methods (such as "**Any**" and "**FirstOrDefault**" methods)?

Comment: After reading more carefully, the case is simple you have an entity instance not being tracked by entity framework. or STEs, Its not supported any more on EF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let look at the first two statements:

```
var entityId = 13;
...

// This is "false"
var hasEntityWithValue = db.MyEntity.Any(p => p.Id == entityId && p.MyProperty1 != null);

// The "myEntity" is null
var myEntity = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == entityId && p.MyProperty1 != null);
```

Both of these sends the same query to the database:

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntities WHERE ID = 13 AND MyProperty1 IS NOT NULL
```

This returns no records from the database because the database does not yet have the new data - there are no records saved in the database with an ID of 13 where MyProperty1 `IS NOT NULL`.  This is because you have not yet called `db.SaveChanges()`. The first statement turns the result of that SQL statement into a value of `false`, whereas the second statement turns it into a value of `null`.

Moving on to the next statement:

```
// Gets the entity only by Id
myEntity = db.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == entityId);
```

This sends a query to the database like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntities WHERE ID = 13
```

The database *does* have a MyEntitiy with an ID of 13, and it returns that MyEntity to EF.  However, before EF returns the MyEntity to you, EF checks to see if it has a MyEntity with an ID of 13 in its cache.  It does have a cached MyEntity with an ID of 13, so it sends the cached MyEntity.  And the cached MyEntity just so happens to be the one you updated in your call to your custom `ApplyChanges` method.

```
// And when I compare the "MyProperty1" it's "true". Why?????
hasEntityWithValue = myEntity.MyProperty1 != null;
```

The reason this is true is because the entity returned to you is the one that is in the EF cache.

When you make a query with EF, it will send the query to the database, and if records are returned from the database, EF will check it's cache to see if records *with the same key* are in the cache.  If they already exist in the cache, the cached records will be returned in place of the records that were found in the database, even if the cached records are different from the database records.  (for more information on how to get around this caching, see http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/)

The cache checking is done at the point the query is run.  So you could make this call and you would see your updated data:

```
var data = db.MyEntity
    .Where(p => p.Id == entityId)
    .ToList()
    .Where(p => p.MyProperty1 != null);
```

The first `Where` function is processed by the database.  The second is processed in memory wherever your C# code is running.  The `ToList` call forces the query that has been built so far to be sent to the database and run before any more filtering or sorting is done.

---

You can also use a transaction for this, but as you mention, this will lock up resources for the duration of the transaction.  Assuming you are working with EF6, you can do this:

```
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    // Applies the changes
    this.ApplyChanges(db, entityType, entityId, propertyValues);

    db.SaveChanges();    

    // Should be true
    var hasEntityWithValue = db.MyEntity.Any(p => p.Id == entityId && p.MyProperty1!=null);

    // At this point, queries to the database will see the updates you made 
    // in the ApplyChanges method
    var isValid = ValidateSave();

    if (isValid)
    {
        // Assuming no more changes were made since you called db.SaveChanges()
        transaction .Commit(); 
    }
    else
    {
        transaction .Rollback(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I've talked to my coworkers and we decided to do something similar with your first suggestion, that is get the entity by its Id and then check its "MyProperty1".

Answer (score 4):

You're right. When you use 'Any', 'FirstOrDefault' or any other Linq extension methods that look for data a SQL query is used. Because of this, any changes to the objects are not seen (for filtering purposes) unless you call 'SaveChanges'.

There is a way to look at materialized objects, but you'll have to do it manually. You'll have to make a Linq-to-Objects query ONLY on the materialized objects to see if what you want is there. An then, if it's not, make a regular Linq-to-Entities query searching it in the database. DO NOT mix these queries, or you may unleash hell.

To search the materialized objects:

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries<MY_ENTITY>(); // strongly-typed, just an objects set
```

or

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries(); // everything
```

Comment: Thank you @Doug. I could try to use this workaround, but the only problem is that would be necessary do that in a lot of queries, because my flow is:
- First I change manually a main entity and its associated entities.
- Then I call a "**ValidateSave**" method that has a lot of rules and many queries being made directly in the database.
- Finally, if there is no validation errors I call the "**db.SaveChanges**".

And to make matters worse, I need to do that for more than one kind of entity, and there are one "ValidateSave" method for each kind of entity.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to do that **automatically**, by using transaction or something similar? Though I think transaction is not a good idea because the operation can take a while, and consequently lock other database operations.

Answer (score 0):

After I talked to my coworkers we decided to do something similar with the first suggestion of the @CodeThug. So I'm going to change the points of my code that queries "MyEntity" using "Linq to entities" to materialize the entity:

```
myEntity = db.MyEntity.First(p => p.Id == entityId);
var hasEntityWithValue = myEntity.MyProperty1 != null;
```